# Integrating canvas into jsdom

Tags: express, canvas, html2canvas, jsdom

By checking the documentation of jsdom, it seems that canvas is supported. However the only explanation given is:

> jsdom includes support for using the canvas or canvas-prebuilt package to extend any  elements with the canvas API. To make this work, you need to include canvas as a dependency in your project, as a peer of jsdom. If jsdom can find the canvas package, it will use it, but if it's not present, then  elements will behave like s.

This is not helping me at all. I installed **canvas-prebuilt** via **npm** and imported canvas-prebuilt before jsdom

```
import canvas from 'canvas-prebuilt';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
```

Next i want to create a dom object of some html snippet and then insert the html into a canvas with **html2canvas**:

```
const dom = new JSDOM(html);
let domcanvas = await html2canvas(dom, {
  dpi: dpi,
  useCORS: true,
  timeout: 20000
});
```

When executing the code an error is thrown saying:

```
No canvas support
```

I assume that jsdom is not finding the canvas.

### Therefore my question is how to integrate canvas into jsdom?

**Edit**:

So after digging into the JSDom code i found out that JSDom is actually finding the canvas. I figured it out by modifying the code inside *node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js* by adding some console logs to verify that canvas had been found:

```
exports.Canvas = null;
["canvas", "canvas-prebuilt"].some(moduleName => {
  try {
    exports.Canvas = require(moduleName);
    if (typeof exports.Canvas !== "function") {
      console.log(moduleName+' is not a function');
      // In browserify, the require will succeed but return an empty object
      exports.Canvas = null;
    }
    console.log('Successfully found ' + moduleName);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Cannot find ' + moduleName);
    exports.Canvas = null;
  }
  return exports.Canvas !== null;
});
```

In my case the output was:

> Cannot find canvas
>
> Successfully found canvas-prebuilt

Therefore my inital question is thus answered.
The error thrown came from html2canvas since objects like `window`, `document` etc. are not global. A workaround would be to make them global with

```
global.window   = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.Image    = window.Image;
global.Node     = window.Node;
```

however there are several more issues with html2canvas and jsdom which had been mentioned by @Niklas and since they are out of the scope of this question they won't be further discussed here.

Hope this question is anyway helpful to some people.

Comment: probably *"No canvas support"* refers to `import canvas from 'canvas-prebuilt';` and not `JSDOM`. Put whole error message.

Comment: Even if you manage to add canvas support to jsdom, jsdom lacks many of the other features required by html2canvas such as style resolution (i.e. `getComputedStyle`) and layout calculation (i.e. `getBoundingClientRect`)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento the error was thrown by html2canvas. The code fragment that is throwing the error is ```var html2canvasExport = (typeof(document) === "undefined" || typeof(Object.create) !== "function" || typeof(document.createElement("canvas").getContext) !== "function") ? function() {
    return Promise.reject("No canvas support");
} : html2canvas;```

Comment: @Niklas well this is a bummer. My main issue is that IE11 is tainting the canvas and therefore when i try to print my website all svgs are thus blank images. I tried the workaround with canvg but it didn't seem to work either. So the only option i see is to provide a webservice that is independent of the webbrowser used by the client.

Comment: @KOsimo html2canvas is undergoing a complete rewrite at the moment. If you have a minimal example of your problem, could you post it on jsfiddle and open up an issue linking to it on github? I'll try my best to get a fix in for the release of 1.0.0

Comment: @Niklas Thank you for your offer. I tried to create a mwe and it seems to work in IE11. Therefore i first need to figure out why it doesn't work in my actual project and then i might file an issue on your github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied my edit to post it as an answer to my question:

So after digging into the JSDom code i found out that JSDom is actually finding the canvas. I figured it out by modifying the code inside *node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js* by adding some console logs to verify that canvas had been found:

```
exports.Canvas = null;
["canvas", "canvas-prebuilt"].some(moduleName => {
  try {
    exports.Canvas = require(moduleName);
    if (typeof exports.Canvas !== "function") {
      console.log(moduleName+' is not a function');
      // In browserify, the require will succeed but return an empty object
      exports.Canvas = null;
    }
    console.log('Successfully found ' + moduleName);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Cannot find ' + moduleName);
    exports.Canvas = null;
  }
  return exports.Canvas !== null;
});
```

In my case the output was:

> Cannot find canvas
>
> Successfully found canvas-prebuilt

Therefore my inital question is thus answered.
The error thrown came from html2canvas since objects like `window`, `document` etc. are not global. A workaround would be to make them global with

```
global.window   = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.Image    = window.Image;
global.Node     = window.Node;
```

however there are several more issues with html2canvas and jsdom which had been mentioned by @Niklas and since they are out of the scope of this question they won't be further discussed here.

Hope this question is anyway helpful to some people.